# TSQL int/int overflow

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion, number-formatting

I have a column called `Odo` that contains the number of meters in a trip. I would normally divide that by 1000 to display the number of Km's.

The line of code in question:

```
convert(varchar(10), startPos.Distance / 1000)
```

causes the following error

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Procedure sp_report_select_trip_start_and_stop,  Line 7 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
>
> Msg 232, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_report_select_trip_start_and_stop, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Arithmetic overflow error for type varchar, value = 931.785156.

That number is clearly longer than my `varchar`. How do I divide, truncate to 1 decimal place and then convert?

Edit: SQL Server 2008 R2, so `format()` is not available

Comment: **round** e.g. `round(931.785156,1)` or use `format()`

Comment: Ok, distance is a float, not an int as expected.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016)

```
format(startPos.Distance/1000,  '#,###,###.#')
```

Or,

```
convert(varchar(10),cast(startPos.Distance/1000 as decimal(9,1)))
```

You may wish to introduce `round()` into these as well. e.g.

```
format(round(startPos.Distance/1000,1),  '#,###,###.#')
```

or

```
convert(varchar(10),cast(round(startPos.Distance/1000,1) as decimal(9,1)))
```

Comment: 2008r2 so no format() function available
same result, using cast or convert.

Comment: "Same result" ... to what?

Comment: I apologise.  I tested again in a clean window and the last option (with round()) is perfect.